# JPA programmatically define cascading options

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following setup.

```
@Table(name = "CV", schema = "recruiter")
public class CV extends AuditedEntity {
    ....
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Experience> experiences;

@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Education> educations;

@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Certification> certifications;
 ....
}
```

So as you can see I only want ALL operations to be cascaded. After selecting all CVs in the table, I pass the collection to the upper layers which serializes the entity into JSON. The user will modify the entity values and children values as he sees fit.

When the entity comes back it will be deserialized from JSON and merged back into the session:

```
// cv is the deserialization of [{"id":1,"creationDate":1368230400000,"creationUser" ... along with all child entities ( educations, experiences and certifications )
em.merge(cv);
```

Now, normally JPA(Hibernate) will only persist what the user has changed, so we're fine on this point . But what happens if the initially serialized CV does not contain any child properties? What if it is just the result of this JPA query:

```
em.em.createNamedQuery("Select cv from CV"); // no eager loading no nothing.
```

In this case all children of the CV ( experiences, educations, certifications) will not be populated. When doing the merge() operations, all the child relations will be deleted.

So long story short, can I cascade in some cases (when I have the entire graph of modified objects) and NOT cascade in others ( when I just have a plain list of freshly deserialized CVs with no children) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that I know of to do that. If you merge an Object that should have children into the storage but the Object does not have the children, then they will be deleted.

You could write a specific `UPDATE` Statement to match that case. Depending on how many values you have you can also read the object from the DB and call all non-children setter.