# Different CascadeType values for different use cases

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

For JPA, I have a problem with defining things like Cascade Type and orphanRemoval settings in the entity class. To me, defining Cascade Type and orphanRemoval on the Entity is limiting as it assumes you always want these settings to be the same in all scenarios.

However, I can think of many cases where an application may sometimes want orphanRemoval and other times not want orphanRemoval for a given entity. Similarly, applications may sometimes want one cascade type and at other times want a different cascade type for the same Entity.

I was hoping the entity manager would allow you to indicate while doing a merge, persist, etc what the cascade type (or orphanRemoval) should be, but I don't think the api supports that.

Is it possible to use different cascade types or orphanRemoval values for different scenarios?

I found this question [JPA programmaticaly define cascading options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499892/jpa-programmaticaly-define-cascading-options?rq=1) which asks a similar question and the answer appears to be that it is not possible, at least with cascade type. I'm starting to think that I should just not use the cascade type/orphanRemoval for any of my relationships, which means in the cases where I do want children to be saved/updated, I will have to do that manually.

Comment: I have removed your second question, as you should stick to one question per question, and it made your question primarily opinion-based, which would make it off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

> To me, defining Cascade Type and orphanRemoval on the Entity is limiting as it assumes you always want these settings to be the same in all scenarios.

I find that assumption reasonable since the cascade settings in the entity directly relate to Referential Integrity (RI) actions of a corresponding Foreign Key (FK) constraint in the underlying database. If we want those rules to be automatically enforced at the "database" level (which would correspond to the "entity" level in Hibernate) then the database normally expects there to be one rule to follow, e.g.,

```sql
ALTER TABLE Sales.TempSalesReason     
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TempSales_SalesReason FOREIGN KEY (TempID)     
    REFERENCES Sales.SalesReason (SalesReasonID)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE    
;
```

If we want different RI rules to be applied in different circumstances then it is up to our application code to enforce those rules by doing its own UPDATE or DELETE operations on the child table(s), or by blocking the initial database operation that would otherwise trigger the RI rule in the FK constraint (if there was one).